# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezcan todas las noticias en un slider en vez de crearme un slider para cada noticia?

Tags: bootstrap, slider

Quiero que aparezcan las últimas 3 noticias de mi base de datos en un slider pero en vez de hacer eso me crea un slider diferente para cada noticia. Os pongo mi código:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_GET['noticia'])) 
{ 
    if(!empty($_GET['noticia'])) 
    { 
        $id_noticia = (int) mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['noticia']); 
        $query_noticias = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT titulo, ruta_imagen FROM ".$NOTICIAS." WHERE id = '".$id_noticia."' LIMIT 3"); 

    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo 'Debes seleccionar una noticia.'; 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    $query_noticias = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM ".$NOTICIAS.""); 

    while($columna = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_noticias))
    { 

?>  

<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?php echo $columna['ruta_imagen']?>" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $columna['titulo']?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?php echo $columna['ruta_imagen']?>" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $columna['titulo']?></h3>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?php echo $columna['ruta_imagen']?>" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $columna['titulo']?></h3>
        </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
  </a>
</div>

<?
}}
?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1ro . Identificar los componentes del slider

a) contenedor del slider

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
```

b) **GRUPO 1** lista de slides 1 LI por cada slide (el primero lleva class="active")

```
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
```

c) cierre **GRUPO 1** abre **GRUPO 2**

```
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
```

d) **GRUPO 2** los items (slides) uno por cada imagen (el primero lleva class="active")

```
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" 
           src="<?php echo $columna['ruta_imagen']?>" 
           alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $columna['titulo']?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

e) cierre del área slides y controles de navegación

```
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

2do . como hay 2 **GRUPOS** para armar reformulamos el `while`que recorre los resultados asi los guarda en un array

```
    while($columna = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_noticias))
```

pasa a ser

```
    $imagenes = []; // array vacío
    while($columna = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_noticias))
    {
        $imagenes[] = $columna; 
        // en realidad es una fila(row) pero mantengo el nombre del ejemplo
    }
```

luego comprobamos que haya imagenes

```
    if (!empty($imagenes)) {
```

imprimimos la cabecera

```
?>
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <?php
```

loop de imagenes para **GRUPO 1** ($i hace de índice y se usa para saber si es la primer slide)

```
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) { ?>
<li data-target="#slider" 
    data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>" 
    <?php echo ($i==0)?'class="active"':'';?>></li>
   <?php $i++; } ?>
```

cierro **GRUPO 1** abro **GRUPO 2**

```
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
```

loop de imagenes para **GRUPO 2** ($i hace de índice y se usa para saber si es la primer slide)

```
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) { ?>

    <div class="carousel-item<?php echo ($i==0)?' active':'';?>">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" 
           src="<?php echo $imagen['ruta_imagen']?>" 
           alt="<?php echo $imagen['titulo']?>">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?php echo $imagen['titulo']?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php $i++; } ?>
```

por último cierre del area slides, controles de navegación y el if not empty

```
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
  </a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: perfectamente explicado y funciona al 100%. Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Un saludo.